# Strange module loader behavior after monkey patching urllib3

Tags: python, boto3, monkeypatching

I tried to monkey patch [urllib3](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3) to trace [boto3](https://github.com/boto/boto3) requests using [jager](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-client-python). Simplified version of code:

```
from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection
import os
import sys
import boto3

class TracingHTTPConnection(HTTPConnection):
    def send(self, data):
        print(data)
        HTTPConnection.send(self, data)

sys.modules['urllib3.connection'].HTTPConnection = TracingHTTPConnection

from boto3.session import Session

ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
your_bucket = s3.Bucket('colleagial-manager')

print(len([file for file in your_bucket.objects.all()]))
```

But this code, for some reason, doesn't work (no request printed on line 8). But following code does work:

```
from urllib3.connection import HTTPConnection
import os
import sys
import boto3

_send = HTTPConnection.send
def send(self, data):
    print(data)
    _send(self, data)

HTTPConnection.send = send

from boto3.session import Session

ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')

session = Session(aws_access_key_id=ACCESS_KEY,
                  aws_secret_access_key=SECRET_KEY)

s3 = session.resource('s3')
your_bucket = s3.Bucket('colleagial-manager')

print(len([file for file in your_bucket.objects.all()]))
```

I can't find out why. Can someone help me understand, please.

System information:

```
OS: Windows 10 x64
Python 3.7.2
boto3 1.9.20
botocore 1.12.20
urllib3==1.23
```